# how to add column value when date have same month and year in php

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a query result as attached
[image]

I want to sum the column value as per the month and year display in
 column 1 as per the attached image in the below table column 1 show
 dec-2014 in column 1 and the sum of all value of colum2 till this
 month and year.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `GROUP BY column1` then SUM the `column2`

EDIT :

> Asumming your table name is `date_test`

**SQL** :

```
 SELECT MONTHNAME(column1) as month, YEAR(column1) as years , SUM(column2) FROM `date_test` GROUP BY month , years
```

You can see we alias the month and year and use it for the `GROUP BY`

> You can change the name of the table or *concat* the aliased date to fit your format as **Dec 2014**

Comment: i cann't cause in the column 1 there is day wise date and i need to group using month and year

Comment: You can use an alias for months. Wait I'll recreate a code

Comment: @NishaGarg Try this out. I tested it on Mysql db this should work

Comment: i have postgresql as a database and that query is not suported

Comment: @NishaGarg Then find a way to locate the month and year from that date and use it on `GROUP BY`. Structure of those two won't be so different. Maybe PostgreSql doesn't implement the `MONTHNAME` or `YEAR`. But I think the logic will be the same just the syntax.